# Homebrew installation on Mac OS X Failed to connect to raw.githubusercontent.com port 443

Tags: ruby, curl, terminal, homebrew

When I try to install Homebrew, I am getting following connection refused error. Please help me to solve this problem.

```
$ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
curl: (7) Failed to connect to raw.githubusercontent.com port 443: Connection refused
```

Comment: Was trying to set up a brand-new M1 Max Macbook today and encountered this. Setting DNS to Google's worked. Hard to believe that was the fix.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Works for me.  Unless its a real problem with github, which it may be but I'm going to guess that its not, its probably a problem with your connection.

Can you get to the same URL via a browser?

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install

If you get an error there too, you know what your problem is. (Talk to your network admin)

If that works...maybe try doing just the "curl" command in your terminal to see if curl gives a more specific error?

Also, if that does work, save that file to a file on your computer (brew_install.rb) and then run it via

```bash
ruby brew_install.rb
```

Comment: Downloading the file and running the script locally on terminal worked. Thanks!

Comment: Switched to a mobile network and it worked.

Answer (score 38):

If you are behind a proxy, try this:

```
sudo vim /etc/hosts
```

#add the line below and :wq

```
199.232.28.133 raw.githubusercontent.com
```

Comment: For me adding to hosts worked. My VPN was disabled, tried DNS option 8.8.8.8 too, not behind a proxy, but it didn't help.

Comment: Only this one worked for me. I am not using any VPN.

Comment: Thanks man, its working for me. Could you explain how did you come up with this?

Comment: /etc/hosts acts as a local DNS service for your local machine and it overrides the mappings from the DNS server to which your machine is connected over the network. 
You can read more about it in: https://www.manageengine.com/network-monitoring/how-to/how-to-add-static-entry.html

Comment: Only this one worked for me. I didn't have VPN. Thanks a lot

Comment: Surprisingly, this one worked for me. Not behind any kind of proxy.

Comment: maybe you need `:wq!`

Answer (score 28):

First try to open the link in the browser if it doesn't open then changing the DNS is the answer.

For me changing the DNS [image: DNS settings] to 8.8.8.8 worked for me.

DNS settings can be searched for in the system setting which can be launched through spotlight in Mac OS and then changed.

This solved the pertinent issue for me.

Comment: Yes setting the DNS to 8.8.8.8 worked for me too !!!

Comment: Pleasure @AnkitJain

Answer (score 20):

The accepted Answer is outdated now. But based on the answer I solved the problem by:

1. open the home page of brew https://brew.sh/
2. copy the URL from the install cmd and open it on your browser https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh
3. right-click and save it to your computer
4. open a terminal and run it with: /bin/bash path-to/install.sh

Comment: this is is the best way to install it, how easy it is! I am using a vpn on browser, called astrill by the way!

Answer (score 12):

It was a company proxy problem for me and the solution as mentioned [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/46280) worked for me.

`export HTTPS_PROXY=https://<proxy.mycompany>:<port>`

`git config --global https.proxy $HTTPS_PROXY`

`git config --global --get https.proxy`

Answer (score 10):

I had the same error,

`- Disabled VPN`

tried again installing without VPN
It worked for me.

Comment: This worked too. Simplest solution if one is connected via  a vpn to access company resources disconnecting the vpn worked made it work immediately

Answer (score 7):

There are several situations here, you can do following things :

1. reinstall the xcode command line tool by `removing the old tools ($ rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools)` and `xcode-select --install`
2. request web page
   `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install`
   then save it's content to shell file then run it.
3. **change your DNS server to `8.8.8.8`** (This is worked for me : ] )

Finally you should run `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

Answer (score 5):

The method of using ruby is probably outdated, as shown below:

[image: Error logs]

As a better alternative, please set your computer's DNS server to `8.8.8.8`

[image: Setting DNS]

[image: working]

Comment: This one works for me. You can also change it 1.1.1.1

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this a few times on other people's machines and it seems to be fixed after you install xcode, i.e. `xcode-select --install`

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to open the Link on a browser as well. I changed the DNS to 8.8.8.8(Google's Public DNS IP address) and it worked.[image: Google Public DNS IP address]

Comment: That answer is a duplicate of the answer from Prajval Singh?

Answer (score 1):

These steps solved the problem:

1. `xcode-select --install`
2. restart the Mac
3. Execute this command:

   ```
   /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
   ```

and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by the following steps:

1. removing the old tools (`$ rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`)
2. install xcode command line tools again (`$ xcode-select --install`).

Answer (score 1):

so in my case I am using Apple M2 , and I got the same error.
What worked form is - I changed my network. Earlier I was using mobile -hotspot, and I got the error, but after I changed to WIFI, it worked.
Not sure why it happens.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest trick which worked for me was to clone the git repo and run the install.sh file

Go to any dir on your computer and open it in terminal and run.

```
git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/install .
```

then,

```
/bin/bash install.sh
```

then follow the displayed steps to add brew to path.

Answer (score 0):

Check is https proxy is set

> env|grep -I proxy

Then if it is set, remove the env variable

> unset HTTPS_PROXY

Answer (score 0):

Although saving the shell file locally and then running it can solve this problem, but you'll meet it again when you do something similar(e.g. install oh-my-zsh, vim-plug, etc.)

At last, I find the 3rd item of this answer(https://stackoverflow.com/a/61787208/5458745) works best for me, as it can also solve the problem I meet when installing other tools using curl. However instead of changing the DNS, I add 8.8.8.8 to my original DNS server list, which works fine for me.

Change your DNS server to 8.8.8.8 (This is worked for me)

Answer (score 0):

```bash
sudo vim /etc/hosts
```

Once the vim code editor is open add the following line at end of the file

```
199.232.68.133 raw.githubusercontent.com
```

Comment: You should try and provide some additional comments along with your answer to help anyone reading your response better understand.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes. This should be considered especially for very old questions that already have multiple upvoted answers.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

You can visit https://github.com/Homebrew/install/blob/master/install.sh to get this `install.sh` by copy the whole contents.

Then paste it into `install.sh` and run `sh install.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of what @blueskin mentioned first and then what @Ferenc Yim mentioned is what worked for me.

The script also requires sudo access (not necessarily run with a sudo prefix just need admin access)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30795200)

Answer (score 0):

Try switching your network. Connect to a different provider

- Use your phone's hotspot
- Connect to another WiFi with different provider.

For me, the domain was not accessible on my WiFi, but it worked when I switched to my phone hotspot.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually add the host here:

`/etc/hosts`

1. Check the ip address behind `raw.githubusercontent` with a simple whois lookup like https://whois.domaintools.com/githubusercontent.com
2. Copy the ip address
3. Open the hosts file

> sudo vim /etc/hosts

4. Add a line:

> `ip-address-you-copied` raw.githubusercontent.com

5. Save and exit

> :wq!

Answer (score -1):

Disconnect from vpn if you are connected to company vpn and try again to run command.