# curl: (7) Failed to connect to raw.githubusercontent.com port 443: Connection refused

Tags: curl, hyperledger-fabric

I am a newbie to Hyperledger Fabric and I am trying to [install Samples, Binaries and Docker Images.](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) I used this command line:

`curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s`

But I got this error:

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to raw.githubusercontent.com port 443: Connection refused

My machine is Ubuntu 18.04 and I've already made sure the version of curl in my machine is the newest. I've already googled this error and tried what I can, but it still don't work well. Hope you guys can give me some suggestions. Thanks a lot!

Comment: i guess there's a typo there at 'curl -sSL', shouldn't it be curl --ssl instead? with double dash and lower case

Comment: @lamSingjip it works fine for me with the command that you have tried. It might be some issue with the server from where these files are fetched. Try executing this command again hopefully it'll work fine for you too.

Comment: @FernandoRocha Thanks! But I tried to change to "--ssl" and run the command, it still won't work. It's the same error.

Comment: @Trinayan Thanks! But I've already tried many times. It still throws me the same error. I have no idea. My curl version is curl 7.58.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu).

Comment: Okay so might be because your network doesn't allow accessing this url. Try using some proxy-free network.

Comment: @Trinayan But I can open this link using chrome and firefox.

Comment: Try looking out for browsers headers while sending your request, and add same headers to cURL request. Some servers needs some headers that browsers sends default but not cURL.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @GariSingh Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Can you try `curl -v -k -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s` ?

Comment: @GariSingh Thanks. But it still throws the same error. I also tried to write "199.232.4.133 raw.githubusercontent.com"  to my host file and my machine can connect to githubusercontent.com. But it still can not download the samples successfully.

Comment: Can you post the full output of `curl -v -k -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh ` ?

Comment: @GariSingh Hi! I've put the full output into here [link](https://github.com/LamSingjip/curl-error-7/blob/master/full-output).

Comment: hmm ... that looks like you are able to connect

Comment: @GariSingh Yes, the error went away after I put "199.232.4.133 raw.githubusercontent.com" to my host file. But I still can't download the files. [link](https://github.com/LamSingjip/curl-error-7/blob/master/Download%20Failed)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Homebrew installation on Mac OS X Failed to connect to raw.githubusercontent.com port 443](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29910217/homebrew-installation-on-mac-os-x-failed-to-connect-to-raw-githubusercontent-com)

Answer (score 21):

Set your DNS Server to `8.8.8.8`, like in following picture:

[image]

Comment: Why adding DNS will help with port 443: Connection refused? It looks like name is resolved, but connection on given port were rejected.

Comment: There may be a domain name pollution if you don‘t have a proper dns setting. It works for me!

Comment: worked. But why did DNS pollution happen, can you explain why it caused and why `8.8.8.8` worked, will it could have worked with other domains too?

Answer (score 0):

I turned off my Trojan vpn and it worked now. So you may try switching your proxy setting or Internet connection settings. Hope it helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

/bin/zsh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://gitee.com/cunkai/HomebrewCN/raw/master/Homebrew.sh)"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31010107)

Answer (score -3):

changing of dns means changing of operator. 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 DNS are google public dns,its help to collect more data.

Comment: This looks more like a comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62198387/2227743) rather than a new answer.