# Unable to install mariadb on macOs

Tags: installation, mariadb, macos-big-sur

I'm trying to install mariadb on macOs Big Sur(version 11.2.3) with m1 chip. Tried the following official link [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-mariadb-on-macos-using-homebrew/) and [here](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/installing-mariadb-10-1-16-on-mac-os-x-with-homebrew/), but when i run the command

```
brew install mariadb
```

then after some time it gives me this error

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to pkg-containers.githubusercontent.com port 443: Operation timed out
> Error: mariadb: Failed to download resource "mecab"
> Download failed: https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/mecab/blobs/sha256:495c42533a5ea5bdedcf4a95c05e613c3579f626b17d0df0396d8a0ea9328bbe

Any help would be appreciated!.

Answer (score -2):

It is a probably a problem with my connection. Please see more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29910217/homebrew-installation-on-mac-os-x-failed-to-connect-to-raw-githubusercontent-com)

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.