# Error: Invalid usage: `brew services` is supported only on macOS or Linux (with systemd)

Tags: mariadb, macos-big-sur

After installation, i tried to start mariaDB server on macOs Big Sur(version 11.2.3) with m1 chip. Tried the following official link [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-mariadb-on-macos-using-homebrew/) but when i run the command

```
brew services start mariadb
```

then it gives me this error

```
Error: Invalid usage: `brew services` is supported only on macOS or Linux (with systemd)!
```

Any thought?

Answer (score 1):

When it runs, [`brew services` checks](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-services/blob/75e051a0c8e0521385514307030faa0243d70693/cmd/services.rb#L54) for a supported system control command:

```
    if !Service::ServicesCli.launchctl? && !Service::ServicesCli.systemctl?
      raise UsageError,
            "`brew services` is supported only on macOS or Linux (with systemd)!"
    end
```

Under macOS, `launchctl?` [checks for the presence](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-services/blob/75e051a0c8e0521385514307030faa0243d70693/lib/service/services_cli.rb#L15) of the `launchtl` command:

```
    # Path to launchctl binary.
    def launchctl
      @launchctl ||= which("launchctl")
    end
```

If this check is failing, you may need to identify whether the command is missing, or something is wrong with `brew`'s installation.

Answer (score -1):

Probably a problem with your connection. If you still having errors, talk with network admin or switch another network connection. Please see more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29910217/homebrew-installation-on-mac-os-x-failed-to-connect-to-raw-githubusercontent-com)